# How to connect activities (android studio 1.2)

Tags: android, android-studio

The biggest problem is that most of tutorials are for earlier version of Android - and the solutions simply don't work on AS1.2. And the word "deprecated" is very confusing for Android newbie.

I'm trying to do very simple app - MainActivity with only one menu option - settings.

So I create the new project (template Blank Activity) and then New -> Activity -> Settings Activity. When I Run App the Main Activity appears on screen, the menu has one option Setting - but it doesn't work - what is expected, because I didn't add any code to MainActivity. But After 5 days of digging and copy pasting "solutions" I'm still on the same point. No reaction - I still have two not connected activities.

I'm sure that I have add some code here:

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

   // TB: HERE Should Setting Activity be shown
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The best code I found (the most clear):

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  return true;
}
```

But - no reaction...

*** updated ***

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.b6a.test4" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="pl.b6a.test4.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*** updated 2 ***

I found that pressing Settings menu item the app isn't doing nothing but is crashing... maybe this is a hint?

*** logs ***
Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug
:app:zipalignDebug
:app:assembleDebug

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 24.012 secs
```

ADB LOGS:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_i9070-FExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\tombrz\AndroidStudioProjects\Test4\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/pl.b6a.test4
No apk changes detected. Skipping file upload, force stopping package instead.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am force-stop pl.b6a.test4
Launching application: pl.b6a.test4/pl.b6a.test4.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "pl.b6a.test4/pl.b6a.test4.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=pl.b6a.test4/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: "and the solutions simply don't work on AS1.2" -- then perhaps you should be asking questions of the form, "this tutorial said that I should do X, but how do I do the same thing in Android Studio 1.2, which is different than what the tutorial uses?".

Comment: What do you mean "have you added Activity to your project" - As I wrote I press New->Activity->Settings Activity, and the SettingsActivity.java class appears in project. And I don't know how to join MainActivity with SettingsActivity

Comment: @ComonsWare Unfortunately there's no effective way to exclude results - I'm googling for 1.2 but got only earlier versions results.

Comment: @SledgehammerPL Yeah, I saw that. The code you have in your question should work.

Comment: that code *must* launch your settings activity. have you checked the id? have you declared SettingsActivity in the manifest?

Comment: @SledgehammerPL I just tested this myself.  Adding the SettingsActivity through the wizard should automatically update the AndroidManifest.xml and your code should work.  It works for me.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent updated question - yes it is in manifest - but pressing Settings does nothing

Comment: Try taking out the parent activity section, so that it's just: `<activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>`

Comment: @DanielNugent - no. No changes. But I found that the app is crashing after touching the menu not doing nothing. maybe this is a hint?

Comment: @SledgehammerPL  Post your logs.

Comment: Post your logcat logs, click the logcat tab next to the ADB tab.

Comment: @DanielNugent logcat is empty

Answer (score 0):

Remove

Return true

from if clause {
}
Bring it outside 
Or just make it false

Comment: @SledgehammerPL Be sure to change your code back to how you have it in the question.  It is correct as is.

Comment: @DanielNugent - yes I know.

Comment: You have this code in your main activity right . not in SettingsAcivity

Comment: @khawar I know, but it does nothing

Comment: @SledgehammerPL it should be very easy task. I don't understand why its not working for you. Kindly post your error log. Where it says caused by: